# How to send Email in Enterprise GitHub actions with attachment and path of the reports?

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, github-pages, github-for-windows

I am  new to GitHub Actions and have tried to send email by using below action and it worked.

```
- name: Send mail
  uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
```

Now, I'am working in GitHub Enterprise, so how can I send an email to a user? This action is not recognizing in enterprise GitHub.

Any suggestions that would be great helpful to me.

---

### 2nd Question

Is there any limitation of giving inputs under `workflow_dispatch`, it is showing only 10 in enterprise. So, any idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). If you have two questions, please do not put them into one as Stackoverflow works best by asking one question at a time. This should then better work towards your expected suggestions and solutions, and nothing to thank in advance for, you're welcome!

Comment: And please edit your question and move the second question out of it, perhaps a new one (I don't know if SO allows this immediatly when you have just signed up, but I'd guess so. If you can't ask a second question right now, please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical network problem. Discuss the issue with the appropriate department running the enterprise Github and find out which policies you have to match and rules you have to follow to become able to send emails from within Github Actions workflow workloads on those systems. They should be able to tell you.

---

The action **dawidd6/action-send-mail** is well accepted for sending emails in Github Actions and I do not see a reason why it should - by the action itself - not work on Github Enterprise.

When you browse the development documentation online, you can also learn about users running that action on internal infrastructure that have contributed changes to it (#59/60).

---

And if you'd like to dabble yourself a bit trouble-shooting from within the workflow, there is [swaks](https://github.com/jetmore/swaks) and [tunshell](https://tunshell.com/) might be of use. Perhaps you're able to find the correct SMTP configuration this way. But just asking the admin for the correct settings is likely easier, especially if network traffic is actually blocked.

Comment: Great, do you have any idea on what permissions do I need to take from organization and if you have any script related to send email through enterprise GitHub actions please provide here. That would be helpful to me. Thank you!!

Comment: That heavily depends on their organization and network configuration, both for the permissions as well as for any handling of that within a script. Apropos script, go with dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3 and clarify your configuration problem of it with your network department. Don't try to address both ends at the same time. The Github Action you have is fine. Just clarify the technical configuration details with your network department. Schedule a meeting with them to discuss how you can setup the testcase.

Comment: And if you'd like to dabble yourself a bit trouble-shooting from within the workflow, there is [swaks](https://github.com/jetmore/swaks) and [tunshell](https://tunshell.com/) might be of use. Perhaps you're able to find the correct SMTP configuration this way. But just asking the admin for the correct settings is probably easier. Take care!